# I want to bind database table to dropdownlist without duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I set `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` to columns in the database table.

The `DataValueField` will be Value for the dropdownlist and `DataTextField` is text for the dropdownlist.

The table has repeating values. The dropdownlist also shows the duplicate values that are present in the text field. I want unique values in the dropdownlist although the `DataTextfield` has repeating values.

Below is my code so far:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select DoctorId, Location from DoctorR", con);
con.Open();

ddlLocation.DataSource= cmd.ExecuteReader();
ddlLocation.DataTextField = "Location";
ddlLocation.DataValueField = "DoctorId";
ddlLocation.DataBind();

ListItem liLocation = new ListItem("Select Location", "-1");
ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, liLocation);

con.Close();
```

The `Location` column has repeating values. I do not want duplicate values to be bound to the dropdownlist.

Comment: But if you have 5 rows with a repeating `Location` but different `DoctorId` values - **which one** of those five rows do you want to show?!?!?!?

Comment: let us say, first row

Comment: does it solved? have you followed below comments?

Comment: Hi Farhang, I used Select distinct Location from DoctorR;  I commented - ddlLocation.DataValueField = "DoctorId"; I will check your solution as well .

Answer (score 2):

you have to use **Distinct** keyword in data source when retrieving data from your database so
duplicate values are not come. just in your sqlcommand try `Select DISTINCT DoctorId,Location from DoctorR` instead of `Select DoctorId,Location from DoctorR`

Comment: Distinct is not getting applied to 'Location'. Some how i am getting duplicates.

Comment: so you mean you have some variouse DoctorIds with same locations ? yes?

Comment: yes... I have various DoctorIds with same locations

Comment: then if you do not display all locations then you will lost the **DoctorId** of them in the dropdown list, do you need the doctorId in DropDownList? I mean do you get it after selection from user or you want it just for displaying locations?

Comment: I want it to just display Locations .

Comment: so just change the sqlcommand to  **Select distinct 1 as DoctorId,Location from DoctorR** (I'm not sure but I think it should work for dropdownlist, if not tell to say another way)

Comment: also you can use this sqlcommand for dropdownlist **Select distinct Location as DoctorId,Location from DoctorR**